# Measuring time of the process/thread in user mode and in kernel on behalf of the process/thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, time

Imagine process/thread is running from point A to point B.

I can get how much time the code execution took by taking two `gettimeofday()` and calculating the difference (wall clock time). However, it may happen, that during the 'route' from A to B CPU was switching to another processes, to drivers, kernel, and other stuff it must perform to keep system running.

Is it possible somehow identify how much time A to B took in terms of actual process/thread execution, and kernel time related to their execution?

The goal for this exercise is to actually identify how much time CPU was NOT executing process/thread or its system calls by executing something else that them.

I am using C.

Comment: Are you using C and can use standard system calls?

Comment: @cyberbrain apologies, yes I use C.

Comment: You could look at how the C++ [std::clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) function is implemented on your system.  At some level it will use a C library function or system call.

Comment: You could also look at [CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID and CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_gettime.3.html). But **NOTE!** I don't know whether those measure _all_ of the CPU time used by a process or a thread, or only the user-mode CPU time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow checked: on my linux implementation (openwrt on ARM9) it shows sum of both user and kernel times.

Answer (score 0):

Searching the man-pages from `time (1)` backwards I found this:
You can use `getrusage`:

> getrusage()  returns resource usage measures

can be used for the own process (self), child processes or the calling thread.

Amongst other values it will give you the *user CPU time used* and the *system CPU time used*.

Please see `man 2 getrusage` for the details. (Or use an online replacement like https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage)